# Loop through each JSON record using backbone and display in a list

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

I've got a collection that does a url request,

```
class Movieseat.Collections.Moviesearch extends Backbone.Collection

  url: ->
    "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=a8f7039633f2065942cd8a28d7cadad4&query=#{@query}"

  setQuery: (q) ->
    @query = q
    return
```

I've got a view that renders a template, in the template is a input field. When text is typed in the input field the Collection gets updated with the value and when there's a keyup action in the input field the collection gets fetched.

```
class Movieseat.Views.Moviesearch extends Backbone.View

  template: JST['movieseats/moviesearch']
  el: '#moviesearch'

  initialize: (opts) ->
    {@collection} = opts
    @render()
    return

  render: ->
    $(@el).html(@template())
    return

  events:
    "keyup input": "doSearch"

  doSearch: (e) ->
    inputtext = @$("form#autocomplete-remote input").val()
    console.log inputtext
    @collection.setQuery $(e.currentTarget).val()
    @collection.fetch()
```

And now I'm trying to render each result in a `li` element, but I don't know how to do that. What would be the next step for me?

Comment: Can you create code snippet?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dxpowx27/92/

Comment: Backbone version used in fiddle is 0.5.3, last stable version is 1.1.2. Could we use last one?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dxpowx27/119/ Updated it with the latest Backbone and Underscore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a little play with your source code I came up with the following solution:

```js
MoviesCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: function () {
        return "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=a8f7039633f2065942cd8a28d7cadad4&query=" + this.query;
    },
    setQuery: function (q) {
        this.query = q;
    },
    parse: function (response) {
        return response.results;
    }
});

ResultsView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function (opts) {
        this.collection = opts.collection ;
        this.collection.on('sync',  this.render, this);
    },
    el: '#result-list', 
    template: _.template($("#results_template").html()),
    render: function () {
        var that = this;
        this.$el.html(this.template({movies:  this.collection.toJSON()}));
    }
});

MoviesView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function (opts) {
        this.collection = opts.collection;
        this.render();
    },
    pressDelay: 500,
    el: "#search_container",
    template: _.template($("#search_template").html()),
    render: function(){
      this.$el.html(this.template());
        var resultsView = new ResultsView({collection: this.collection})  ;
        resultsView.render();
    },
    events: {
        'keyup input': 'doSearch'
    },
    doSearch: function (event) {
        if (this.timeoutId) {
          clearTimeout(this.timeoutId);
        }
        this.timeoutId = setTimeout($.proxy(this.fetchValues, this), this.pressDelay);
        
    },
    fetchValues:  function() {
        // add check here for empty values, no need to fetch collection if input is empty
        var inputtext =  this.$el.find('input').val();
        console.log (inputtext);
        var that = this;
        this.collection.setQuery(inputtext);
        this.collection.fetch();
    }
    
});

myCollection = new MoviesCollection();

var search_view = new MoviesView({
    collection: myCollection
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.7.0/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.1.2/backbone-min.js"></script>

<script type="text/template" id="results_template">
    <ul id="search_container-results">
        <% _.each(movies, function(movie) { %> 
        <li class="original_title"><%= movie.title %></li> 
        <% }); %>
     </ul>
</script>
    
 <div id="search_container"></div>

<script type="text/template" id="search_template">
    <form id="autocomplete-remote">
        <input type="text" id="search_input" value="Star" />
        <input type="button" id="search_button" value="Search" />
    </form>
    <div id="result-list">
        
    </div>
</script>
```

I have added timeout between input events, to increase queries frequency. You can configure it using `pressDelay` property of `MoviesView`.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [listenTo](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-listenTo) and [the list of built in events.](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog)

I think you probably want to listen to the collection's events and call a render method when something changes.

For example, you could add this to your initialize to re-render when the collection is fetched:

```
this.listenTo(this.collection, 'sync', this.render);
```

Or you could just render a single item when it's added to the collection:

```
this.listenTo(this.collection, 'add', this.renderItem);
```

Comment: it looks like your a step ahead of me. I should indeed watch for changes on the collection to update my DOM. But if you take it one step back you can see that I don't have a way yet to render out the JSON to a nice li element.